# Using PSCredential Object to authenticate commands non-interactively

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication

I am using the PSCredential Object to authenticate a command, which I need to be run as a different user. 
I get the following on the powershell cli.

```
> whoami
dmn1\srveikafka
> $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
> $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("srveizookeeper", $secpasswd)
>
> $sess = new-pssession -computername remotecomputer.xyz.com -credential $mycreds
> invoke-command -session $sess -scriptblock {whoami}
dmn1\srveizookeeper
```

But when I run these same commands as a powershell script I get this error.

```
new-pssession : [remotecomputer.xyz.com] Connecting to remote server remotecomputer.xyz.com failed with the following
error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\workstation\add_zookeeper_spn.ps1:13 char:9
+ $sess = new-pssession -computername remotecomputer.xyz.com -credential $mycreds
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
   gTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\workstation\add_zookeeper_spn.ps1:14 char:25
+ invoke-command -session $sess -scriptblock {whoami}
+                         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

What am I getting wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include the domain as part of the username in the credential constructor:

```
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("dmn1\srveizookeeper", $secpasswd)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to a remote machine without any pop-up for credentials

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force -Verbose

Set-WsManQuickConfig

winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="your-remote-Ip"}'

Restart-Service WinRM

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "remote-password" -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("your-remote-ip\remote-username", $secpasswd)
```

to enter into the remote server from your machine

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName your-remote-ip -Credential $mycreds
Enter-PSSession $Session
```